# How to install pandas on Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sublimetext3

I'm fairly new to Python - I am using 2.7 and SublimeText3.
I can't seem to install Pandas.  I was able to install andaconda, but when I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

It shows

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

What should I be doing in order to get this to work properly? (Does Pandas simply not work with SublimeText3?)

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Answer (score 2):

For me worked creating the file `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Python/Python3.sublime-build` with

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/home/tercio/anaconda3/bin/"
}
```

Here `"path": "/home/tercio/anaconda3/bin/"` is the path that is installed the anaconda3 in my computer. Replace this information with that path.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows (Hopefully you have Pip), open cmd and run:

```
pip install pandas
```

For Linux , use same command on terminal

Then try above gain.

Comment: I already have pandas installed via pip and I'm having the same problem as the parent with Sublime 3 in Linux Mint.  All other modules load as expected.  I'm using python 3.6 via `virtualENV`.  The script runs fine from my virtual term.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing text editors and shells.

Sublime Text is a text editor which allows you to write code in whatever program language you want, you should see it as a paper sheet. You can really write whatever you want in a paper sheet.

Shells on the other hand are the program which are able to understand and execute the code you have written in a text editor. You can have a python a shell (a shell which executes python codes) in programs like Idle or Jupyter, and in your command prompt after typing `python3` assuming you have installed python with a version >= 3

Answer (score 0):

First check what version of sublime text you are using. Use this to check:
print(sys.version)

The result shows: 2.7.16

Also, check in your Terminal using this command:
first check: python --version
Then check Python3, if it is available: python3 --version

If you have Python3, then your system won't allow you to install Pandas in Python 3. That time use this line of code to install Pandas:
pip3 install pandas

Then, go to Sublime Text3-->Tools-->Build System-->Python3

I have been facing same problem, and my problem has been resolved using this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only thing that worked in my case was to uninstall pandas using pip and then install it again.

```
pip uninstall pandas

pip install pandas
```